# how to return rating on a span element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a interactive rating component. I have no clue how I can return the result on a span element after a rating is chosen.

When I enter the rating on buttons:

[image]

After I submit the rating:

[image]

There I want to return the result.

I was trying an if statement in the forEach function but didn't know how to return the result on the span element.

```js
const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');


allBtns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
  })
});

function ShowAndHide() {

  let y = document.querySelector('.ratingbox');
  let x = document.querySelector('.thankyou');
  if (x.style.display == 'none') {
    y.style.display = 'none';
    x.style.display = 'block';


  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="ratingbox">
  <div class="backgroundstar">
    <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="" class="star">
  </div>

  <div class="writing">
    <h1>How did we do?</h1>

    <p>Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback is appreciated to help us improve our offering! </p>
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox">
    <ul>
      <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">1</p></button></li>
      <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">2</p></button></li>
      <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">3</p></button></li>
      <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">4</p></button></li>
      <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">5</p></button></li>
    </ul>

    <button class="submit" onclick="ShowAndHide()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="thankyou " style="display: none; ">
  <div class="message ">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt=" " class="img ">
    
    <div class="selected ">
      <span id="rating "></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="greeting ">
      <h2>Thank you!</h2>
      
      <p id="appreciate ">We appreciate you taking the thime to give a rating.<br> If you ever need more support, don't hesitate to <br> get in touch!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "return the result" where? Are you just trying to figure out what rating was chosen after the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Does the demo above show the problem? FYI, I removed an extra quotation mark from your button and an orphaned closing main tag.

Comment: It's invalid HTML to have a paragraph inside a button. I'd use spans there.

Comment: It's invalid to have ID values that aren't unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the right tool for the job.

Use radio buttons to manage your rating and style the labels how you'd like. Then use CSS to handle hiding and showing. Leave JavaScript to manipulating the DOM.

Keep in mind IDs **need** to be unique. Once they are no longer unique, they are no longer ids. Things like `document.getElementById` will break if ID is not unique.

```js
/*Get out radio buttons based on the name attribue*/
const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('[name=rating]');


/*Add the event listener*/
allBtns.forEach(btn => {    
  btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {     
   /*Update the text using the value of the radio button*/
   document.querySelector("#rating").innerHTML = `Thanks for rating us ${this.value}!`;
  })
});

function ShowAndHide() {
  /*Toggle the hide class on the appropriate boxes*/
  document.querySelector('.ratingbox').classList.toggle("hide");
  document.querySelector('.thankyou').classList.toggle("hide");;  
}
```

```css
/*Hide the radion buttons*/
.flexbox input {display:none;}

/*Give some buttonish styling to the check boxes */
.flexbox label {
  display:block;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  height: 30px;
  width:30px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

/*Change the styling of the checked label*/
/*Note the use of the adjacent sibling cominator + */
.flexbox :checked + label  {
  background-color: orange;
}

/*Generic class to handle showing and hiding*/
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratingbox">
  <div class="backgroundstar">
    <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="" class="star">
  </div>

  <div class="writing">
    <h1>How did we do?</h1>

    <p>Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback is appreciated to help us improve our offering! </p>
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox">
    <ul>
      <!-- Using radio buttons , that will be hidden with associated labels -->
      <li><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rtr1" value="1"><label for="rtr1">1</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rtr2" value="2"><label for="rtr2">2</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rtr3" value="3"><label for="rtr3">3</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rtr4" value="4"><label for="rtr4">4</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rtr5" value="5"><label for="rtr5">5</label></li>
    </ul>

    <button class="submit" onclick="ShowAndHide()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="thankyou hide">
  <div class="message ">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt=" " class="img ">
    
    <div class="selected ">
      <span id="rating"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="greeting ">
      <h2>Thank you!</h2>
      
      <p id="appreciate ">We appreciate you taking the thime to give a rating.<br> If you ever need more support, don't hesitate to <br> get in touch!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i center the numbers ?

Comment: Do you mean in the circles? They already are.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code. The main issue is you are using the same `id`, `num`, for multiple elements, which is invalid. Change those `id`'s to `class` instead, like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li><button class="btn"><p class="num">1</p></button></li>
    <li><button class="btn"><p class="num">2</p></button></li>
    <li><button class="btn"><p class="num">3</p></button></li>
    <li><button class="btn"><p class="num">4</p></button></li>
    <li><button class="btn"><p class="num">5</p></button></li>
</ul>
```

After doing that, one way to acquire the most recently selected button is to find the nested `.num` within your button click eventListeners, such as `var rating = parseInt(btn.querySelector(".num").textContent)`

Here is how you might do that with minimal changes to your current code:

```js
const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
var currentRating = null;

allBtns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
    currentRating = parseInt(btn.querySelector(".num").textContent)
  })
});

function ShowAndHide() {
  if (currentRating){
    alert(currentRating);
  }
  let y = document.querySelector('.ratingbox');
  let x = document.querySelector('.thankyou');
  if (x.style.display == 'none') {
    y.style.display = 'none';
    x.style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Here is a JsFiddle that does just this and alerts the selected rating:
https://jsfiddle.net/eg4Ly0nd/

Note: I would recommend using hidden checkbox inputs within each of the `li` buttons and adding to code your event listener to check the selected input associated with a button and uncheck the others. Then you don't need the global `currentRating` variable that is included in my solution; you can just find the input that is checked. I only wrote it this way to make minimal changes to the code you provided while still giving a solution.

Comment: got Uncaught TypeError: btn.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: @RobinLeitner do you get that within your code or within the JS fiddle I shared? If it's within your code and not the JS fiddle, make sure you are making the appropriate changes, most likely changing the `id` attribute to `class` where I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution, you can set the `rating` value for each button by Javascript only, and with minimal change to existing code.

This way, it is independent to any content in `p`. It also saves the trouble of reading the `p` tag, since you might need to replace it with something else according to design.

The below Javascript snippet can be used with your posted HTML without changes.

Full example (run it with the button below for demo):

```js
const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const resultSpan = document.querySelector(".selected span")

allBtns.forEach((btn, i) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';

    // Customize the output text here
    // It displays in Success screen
    resultSpan.innerText = `You have rated ${i + 1}`;
  })
});

function ShowAndHide() {

  let y = document.querySelector('.ratingbox');
  let x = document.querySelector('.thankyou');
  if (x.style.display == 'none') {
    y.style.display = 'none';
    x.style.display = 'block';


  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="ratingbox">
  <div class="backgroundstar">
    <img src="images/icon-star.svg" alt="" class="star">
  </div>

  <div class="writing">
    <h1>How did we do?</h1>

    <p>Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback is appreciated to help us improve our offering! </p>
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox">
    <ul>
      <li><button class="btn"><p>1</p></button></li>
      <li><button class="btn"><p>2</p></button></li>
      <li><button class="btn"><p>3</p></button></li>
      <li><button class="btn"><p>4</p></button></li>
      <li><button class="btn"><p>5</p></button></li>
    </ul>

    <button class="submit" onclick="ShowAndHide()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="thankyou " style="display: none; ">
  <div class="message ">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt=" " class="img ">
    
    <div class="selected ">
      <span id="rating "></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="greeting ">
      <h2>Thank you!</h2>
      
      <p id="appreciate ">We appreciate you taking the thime to give a rating.<br> If you ever need more support, don't hesitate to <br> get in touch!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But as other comments mentioned, it is recommended that you assign a different `id` for each `p`, or no `id` at all since no need to read these tags in code anyway.